# Simultaneously training many models based on the same raw data

Tags: python, dask

Suppose, I have raw data C. I break C into 100 columns called A1, A2, ... A100. I want to train 100 k-means models each based on one of the A arrays.

If I use dask-ml, can dask-ml avoid reading raw data C from the hard disk for 100 times?

Update (Try to test the delay idea):

```
from dask_ml.cluster import PartialMiniBatchKMeans
from dask_ml.datasets import make_classification
from dask.delayed import delayed
from dask import compute
import numpy as np
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, chunks=500)
N = 2
est = [PartialMiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=2) for i in range(N)]

d_est = [delayed(est[i].fit(X)) for i in range(N)]

com = compute(*d_est)
#[d.compute() for d in d_est]
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': lambda x: "{0:0.2f}".format(x)})
for i, c in enumerate(com):
    print("---- model #%d ----" % i)
    for cen in c.cluster_centers_:
        print(cen)
```

Result:

```
---- model #0 ----
[1.05 0.01 0.12 0.06 -0.65 0.06 -0.80 -0.04 -0.10 0.08 0.09 -0.04 -0.08
 0.13 -0.06 -0.07 0.06 0.60 0.13 0.02]
[-1.29 -0.11 -0.13 -0.02 0.80 -0.02 0.98 -0.05 0.21 -0.06 -0.15 0.11 0.03
 -0.07 0.16 0.14 -0.11 -0.73 -0.04 0.00]
---- model #1 ----
[0.95 -0.03 -0.01 0.09 -0.46 0.07 -0.69 0.03 -0.06 -0.06 -0.07 0.04 -0.04
 0.10 0.01 0.02 -0.15 0.71 0.03 -0.01]
[-1.36 -0.06 0.03 -0.07 0.66 -0.04 0.98 -0.16 0.18 0.13 0.07 0.01 -0.02
 -0.04 0.08 0.01 0.19 -1.02 0.10 0.04]
```

The two delayed minibatch kmeans models don't give the same centroid when I train the two models simultaneously on exactly the same data.

That still doesn't prove if dask-ml can avoid reading the data for 100 times though... Probably dask just roll different random numbers for the initialization of the two models.

Comment: I would think no, but I am not sure.

Comment: Wait. Can I just delay calling the fit methods on all those models, and then compute those delay objects simultaneously?

Comment: I think you answered your own question :)  You may also want to consider using the distributed scheduler's [scatter](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.client.Client.scatter) method with broadcast.

Comment: That is nice! So delay works. I have to check what scatter does.

Comment: You may want to show your completed solution and accept your own answer.